# BigQuery querying data directly from Storage with Datastore exported file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I am wondering if BigQuery support to query Datastore exported file stores in Cloud Storage? The [sample code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/cf04f6d15615b09c1de9e584bb3462653f0770f1/bigquery/docs/snippets.py) only shows that how to query **CSV** and **GOOGLE_SHEETS**, but Datastore exported file is "kinds.export_metadata". If it's supported, what `ExternalConfig` should be? Any example for reference?

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExternalConfig is referring to an external source.

BigQuery support 3 external sources type as defined in [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources)

Cloud storage file Formats are defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage)

> Comma-separated values (CSV)
>
> JSON (newline-delimited)
>
> Avro files
>
> Cloud Datastore exports
>
> Cloud Firestore exports

As a reference, This is how it looks in the Python implementation [code from github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/cf04f6d15615b09c1de9e584bb3462653f0770f1/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/external_config.py)

```
CSV = 'CSV'
    """Specifies CSV format."""

    GOOGLE_SHEETS = 'GOOGLE_SHEETS'
    """Specifies Google Sheets format."""

    NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
    """Specifies newline delimited JSON format."""

    AVRO = 'AVRO'
    """Specifies Avro format."""

    DATASTORE_BACKUP = 'DATASTORE_BACKUP'
    """Specifies datastore backup format"""

    BIGTABLE = 'BIGTABLE'
    """Specifies Bigtable format."""
```

So if your file is in one of those formats you are good to go